# Нужна помощь с оператором расширения и строками. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Как сделать так, чтобы оператор расширения записывал по отдельности каждую букву? Ожидал что будет выводить каждую букву отдельно в строку, но выходит по другому, помогите мне пожалуйста, не могу понять как правильно сделать.

```
let strings = ['Привет','UseName!'];
let stringsAll = [...strings];
console.log(stringsAll);
```

можно конечно записать так:

```
let strings = [...'Привет',...'UseName!'];
console.log(stringsAll);
```

но хочу узнать как реализовать не меня 1 массив.
Вопрос глупый, но не смогу уснуть пока не узнаю как.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исходя из вопроса, это будет выглядеть так:

```js
let strings = ['Привет','UseName!'];
let stringsAll = [...strings.join('')];

console.log(stringsAll);
```

Comment: спасибо, да лёгкое решение, но сам бы не додумался бы, слишком тупой. )

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вариант с `join` лучше, но всё же:

```js
let strings = ['Привет', 'UseName!'];
let stringsAll = strings.flatMap(s => [...s]);
console.log(stringsAll);
```